# Headless UI component will not take style

Tags: vue.js, vite, headless-ui

I'm currently playing around with Headless UI and I can't seem to style any of the components.
This is the code in my tabs file

```
<template>
  <TabGroup>
    <TabList class="bg-blue-900/20 rounded-xl">
      <Tab>Products Information</Tab>
      <Tab>Find Offices Nearby</Tab>
      <Tab>Requirements</Tab>
    </TabList>
    <TabPanels>
      <TabPanel>Content 1</TabPanel>
      <TabPanel>Content 2</TabPanel>
      <TabPanel>Content 3</TabPanel>
    </TabPanels>
  </TabGroup>
</template>

<script>
  import { TabGroup, TabList, Tab, TabPanels, TabPanel } from '@headlessui/vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      TabGroup,
      TabList,
      Tab,
      TabPanels,
      TabPanel,
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's either of these problems

1. Tailwind CSS is not installed or configured properly so you cannot use Tailwind CSS classes like 'rounded-xl'.
2. 'bg-blue-900/20' is not an inbuilt tailwind CSS class, so either [customize color](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors) in tailwind or use inbuilt colours like 'bg-blue-400', 'bg-blue-500', etc

Answer (score 0):

Tailwindcss v2.1 introduced JIT mode that generates styles on-demand.

You need to enable jit mode to use such classes like `bg-blug-900/20`.

You can see how to do that in [official doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode)